# What doesn't work in this number matching regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am running Python 2.7 and I am currently having some issue with [RE library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).
As a simple example, when trying numbers on a human written document, I wrote this regular expression :

```
import re
number = r'^[(]?([-]?([ ]?\d[ ]?)+)|([-]?([ ]?\d[ ]?)+[.,]([ ]?\d[ ]?)*)[)]?$'
```

This is supposed to match numbers with comas, dots and blanks because humans don't always format it well, and with or without `-`, `(`and `)`.

Even if they are not optimized, I expected the following expressions to work, but they obviously don't as we can see on the screenshot.

```
ex1 = r'^[(]?([-]?([ ]?\d[ ]?)+)|([-]?([ ]?\d[ ]?)+[.,]([ ]?\d[ ]?)*)[)]?$'
ex2 = r'^(\()?(-)?( ?\d ?)*[.,]?( ?\d ?)*(\))?$'
ex3 = r'^[(]?(-)?( ?\d ?)*[.,]?( ?\d ?)*[)]?$'
```

[> Screenshot to output <](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtSmn.png)

Input :

```
import re

print "1st example :"
number = r'^[(]?([-]?([ ]?\d[ ]?)+)|([-]?([ ]?\d[ ]?)+[.,]([ ]?\d[ ]?)*)[)]?$'
print re.match(number, "16 juillet 1993")

print "\n2nd example :"
number = r'^(\()?(-)?( ?\d ?)*[.,]?( ?\d ?)*(\))?$'
print re.match(number, "16 juillet 1993")
print re.match(number, "161993")
print re.match(number, "-1619,93")
print re.match(number, "-( 9 9 . 3 )")

print "\n3rd example :"
number = r'^[(]?(-)?( ?\d ?)*[.,]?( ?\d ?)*[)]?$'
print re.match(number, "-( 9 9 . 3 )")
```

Ouput :

```
1st example :
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103da5480>

2nd example :
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103da5480>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103da5480>
None

3rd example :
None
```

Comment: Please post the sample data as text.

Comment: I expected it to output a `None` for `"16 juillet 1993"` and a match for all the others. With `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of my regex, `re.match` seemed to be what I needed to use. What do you suggest ?

Comment: I would post this `^(?:[ ]*[(])?(?:[ ]*[-])?(?:(?:[ ]*\d)+(?:[ ]*[.,](?:[ ]*\d[ ]*)*)?|[ ]*[.,](?:[ ]*\d)+)(?:[ ]*[)])?$` if you didn't have that `-` outside of parenthesis.

Comment: This is the _template_ you should use to create a regex for whole numbers and fractions `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`. I used it to make the one in my comment above. Some advice, use [RegexFormat](http://www.regexformat.com) to parse and format these big expressions. It will save you time and aggravation.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen `match` and `search` don't seem to be much different when you impose `^` and `$`.

Comment: @sln Thank you for the link, I will look at it. But my main question is why these expressions _doesn't_ work, not other suggestions. Until I understand what's wrong with them, I won't be sure of the regex I'm writing on the spot.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen "Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets. For example, [(+*)] will match any of the literal characters '(', '+', '*', or ')'." ([ref here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html))

Comment: Ok, I am not very farmiliar with re so I'm just going to but out and get rid of my clearly non- helpful comments.

Comment: Indeed for `(-` instead of `-(`, that was stupid. But I don't see how the space is a problem, what I wanted to say is : "If there is a space before or after a digit, I don't care", so my digits are like `( ?\d ?)`.

Comment: Your other regex are matching `-1619,93` and `161993` as it says it returns a regex match object.  I would be more consistent though and put the space inside a class. `^(\()?(-)?([ ]?\d[ ]?)*[.,]?([ ]?\d[ ]?)*(\))?$` and if you can, lose the capture groups, use cluster groups `(?:..)` and when you get it working, use the regex I posted as an example.

Comment: The question now is how does it come that the first regex matches `"16 juillet 1993"`.

Comment: That's fairly easy, you have a single alternation, `^this | that $` it's matching the `^this` one. Better to enclose it in a cluster group `^(?:this | that) $` so the anchors apply to both. Like this `^[(]?(?:([-]?([ ]?\d[ ]?)+)|([-]?([ ]?\d[ ]?)+[.,]([ ]?\d[ ]?)*))[)]?$`

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for the help and the tool.

Comment: Good luck to you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try：`number=r'^-?\(?( ?\d ?)+[.,]?( ?\d ?)*\)?$'`
here, `-`is out side of `(  )`.
If you want match `-` inside of `(  )`, please use:
`number=r'^\(?-?( ?\d ?)+[.,]?( ?\d ?)*\)?$'`

If you want match parentheses`(   )` in string, you should escape it by `\`.